# How to get handle of the first ylabel of a plot generated through plotyy when importing a fig file?

Tags: matlab

So my figures are shown here: http://www.atmos.uw.edu/~akchen0/CERES_Project/

I'd like to run get(get(gca,'YLabel'),'String'), but it only outputs the label of the second y-axis. How can I get the label of the first y-axis?

As a secondary question, what should I do if get(get(gca,'Title'),'String') doesn't display anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all axes handles by:

```
ax = findobj(gcf,'Type','axes','Tag','');
```

or

```
f = hgload( filename )
ax = findobj(f,'Type','axes','Tag','');
```

The **name, value property pair** `'Tag',''` is important, otherwise also legend handles would be returned.

and then you already found out how to proceed:

```
y1Label = get(get(ax(2),'YLabel'),'String')
y2Label = get(get(ax(1),'YLabel'),'String')
xLabel  = get(get(ax(2),'XLabel'),'String')
```

returns:

```
y1Label =
    NH-SH Difference ...

y2Label =
    Heat Flux ...

xLabel =
    Year End
```